# In this problem from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, which integral is being referred to?

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' Complex analysis text, chapter 4, section 5 (the Residue Theorem), problem 2 reads:

"Show that in Sec. 5.3, Example 3, the integral may be extended over a right-angled isosceles triangle."

My question is what integral is he referring to? There are more than one in that example.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't he just asking to use another curve as contour?

Comment: @leo I guess so, but should I do it for the general integral $\int R(x) e^{ix} dx$? Or for the specific $\int \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx$? (or another one?)

Comment: For the specific, I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In section 5.3 Ahlfors shows that $$\lim_{\rho\to\infty}\int_{\gamma(\rho)} R(z)e^{iz}=0\tag1$$
for any rational function $R$ with a zero at $\infty$. Here $\gamma(\rho)$ is the upper semicircle of radius $\rho$. My reading of the exercise is that Ahlfors wants you to show that
(1) remains true (for any rational function $R$ with a zero at $\infty$) if $\gamma(\rho)$ is   replaced by two legs of isosceles right triangle with hypotenuse $[-\rho,\rho]$.

I admit that the double appearance of number 3 in "Sec. 5.3, Example 3" is strange. It may be an inconsistency of numbering that crept into the text; they did not have $\LaTeX$ back then.